# Unity: Line Renderer Collider

Tags: unity3d

Ситуация такая: 2D игра-платформер, игрок рисует курсором мышки произвольную линию на экране, после чего эта линия должна стать физически твердой, чтобы игрок мог взаимодействовать с ней как с твердой платформой. Систему рисования линии я уже написал, используя Line Renderer, теперь осталось как-то сделать, чтобы линия получала правильный коллайдер. Пробовал добавлять Box Collider в каждый угол, но это слишком ресурсозатратно. Пытался использовать Bakemesh, но не вышло. Есть ли еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: а меш коллайдер? https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html

Comment: ну да, после получения меша с помощью bakemesh пытался сделать на меш коллайдере, но нашлась тысяча и одна проблема с этим. Если других способов не отыщу, попытаюсь вновь таким вот